# Get value of array elements

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am using a List(of) to populate an array since the number of elements will change.  A button adds one element to the List(of).  After the List(of) is populated, I am then converting that to an array of type double.  I now want to know the values in the first and last element of the converted array.  I'm stuck after I call getlowerbound and getupperbound.

```
lower = ScaledValsArray.GetLowerBound(0) 'what is value of this element in the array?
upper = ScaledValsArray.GetUpperBound(0) 'what is value of this element in the array?
```

Comment: How is your code not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting lower and upper to the lowest and greatest indices. There are several ways to get the values. The simplest might be:

```
dim firstValue as Double = ScaledValuesArray.First
dim lastValue as Double = ScaledValuesArray.Last
```

You won't need to use the index directly at all.

Answer (score 1):

`ScaledValsArray(0)` returns the first element and `ScaledValsArray(ScaledValsArray.Length - 1)` the last one.